# Spatial Indexes on OS MasterMap Data

Tags: sql-server, ordnance-survey, spatial-index

What are the optimal settings for setting up a SQL Server 2008 Spatial database with full UK OS MasterMap data in?

- Seperate tables for the different feature types, or a single table with everything in it?
- What spatial index settings have you found work best?

Any "best practice" or experience gained would be appreciated.

For reference, I'm using Cadcorp to display the data.

Comment: UK in this case is Great Britain (not including Northern Ireland). Does your full MasterMap contain the aerial imagery too? http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-mastermap/imagery-layer/index.html

Comment: Yes, GB: England, Scotland and Wales. We don't have the aerial imagery yet, but we do have the ITN Topology layer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a layer per feature type (topographic_area, topographic_line etc.). The data is all in Britsh National Grid so you're going to want a geometry index one per table on the geometry column. If you are using Cadcorp to consume the data then I think it has styling support based on a layer per feature type.

I've not loaded OS MasterMap into SQL Server but have loaded PostgreSQL and Oracle previously, if you don't already have a loader then you might like to try the open source loader we (astuntechnology.com) maintain which currently handles OSMM Topo and VML and will handle ITN and OS AddressBase once I push the latest development version. You can find it here:  https://github.com/AstunTechnology/osmmloader

Cheers,

Matt.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We do have a loader, but I'll certainly take a look at yours.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if your data is geography or geometry:

*"When creating an index on a geometry type column, you must specify the (X-min,Y-min) and (X-max,Y-max) coordinates of the bounding box. For an index on a geography type column, the bounding-box fields become read-only after you specify the Geography grid tessellation scheme, because geography grid tessellation does not use a bounding box. "*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964714.aspx

Comment: Thanks for looking. I will be using the Geometry data type, but my question was more asking about for how best to set the parameters of the tesselation scheme withing the index.